# How to create a csv file for each column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, split

I am using Python in VSCode. I read a CSV file and transformed it in a dataframe for stock market's close prices. First column is date column and others are each stock symbol close prices. I would like to split this dataframe with multiple columns into separate .csv files. Each new .csv file will be named as per each stock symbol column´s header´s name.

Below is a link for the dataframe as example (the original file has like 500 coluns and 10,000 rows):

[image]

So, each new .csv file will be named such as `"TAEE11.csv"` and so on contain the respective values down that column keeping the "Date" column for each file as well. I would like to save these newly created .csv files to a new folder (like when you are using Python inside VSCode you can save these new .csv files to a new folder with `*.to_csv`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Since you already have a dataframe
- Set the index of the dataframe as the `'Date'` column
- Iterate through each column and save it to a csv.

  - Select the data for each column with `df[col]`
  - The csv file name will be `f'{col}.csv'`, where `col` is the column name.
- To specify a specific file save location when working in VSCode, see this [SO: Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54227746/pandas-to-csv-doesnt-output-the-file/57503052#57503052)

  - `df.to_csv(os.getcwd()+'\\file.csv')` goes into the `AppData` folder
  - The current working directory is not necessarily where you want the file saved.
  - Specify the full desired save path, `'c:/Users/<<user_name>>/Documents/{col}.csv'`, for example.

```py
import pandas as pd

# set Date as the index
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

# iterate through each column and save it
for col in df.columns:
    df[col].to_csv(f'c:/Users/<<user_name>>/Documents/{col}.csv', index=True)
```

Comment: Dear Trenton! It worked just like a charm! Already checked as requested! If possible I would check many times over! All the best!