# How to read in multiple files as separate dataframes and perform calculations on a column?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, report

I am calculating a single stock return as follow:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'**file**.csv')
data.index = data.Date
data['Return %'] = data['AAPL'].pct_change(-1)*100
data
```

out put:

```
    Date    AAPL    Return %
Data            
2020-09-11  2020-09-11  56.00   0.000000
2020-09-10  2020-09-10  56.00   -3.879162
2020-09-09  2020-09-09  58.26   2.138850
2020-09-08  2020-09-08  57.04   -2.211555
2020-09-04  2020-09-04  58.33   0.882048
2020-09-03  2020-09-03  57.82   -3.585126
2020-09-02  2020-09-02  59.97   -0.133222
```

Now, I have many other csv files as stock symbols saved and I would like to use each of these symbols to perform same calculation above.
On top of that, I would like to print a report for the best day of each of these symbols returns.

If more details needed, pls let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I think the best option for your data is to read the files into a dictionary of dataframes.

  - Use `pathlib` and `.glob` to create a list of all the files
  - Use a dict comprehension to create the dict of dataframes.
- The dictionary can be iterated over in the standard way of dictionaries, with `dict.items()`.
- `df_dict[k]` addresses each dataframe, where `k` is the dict key, which is the file name.
- From your last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63864337), I expect the `.csv` file to be read in with one `Date` column, not two.
- The numeric data for each file should be in the column at index 0, after `Date` is set as the index.

  - Since the column name is different for each file, it's better to use [`.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to address the column.
  - `:` means all rows and `0` is the column index for the numeric data.
- `df_dict.keys()` will return a list of all the keys
- Individually access a dataframe with `df_dict[key]`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

# create the path to the files
p = Path('c:/Users/<<user_name>>/Documents/stock_files')

# get all the files
files = p.glob('*.csv')

# created the dict of dataframes
df_dict = {f.stem: pd.read_csv(f, parse_dates=['Date'], index_col='Date') for f in files}

# apply calculations to each dataframe and update the dataframe
# since the stock data is in column 0 of each dataframe, use .iloc
for k, df in df_dict.items():
    df_dict[k]['Return %'] = df.iloc[:, 0].pct_change(-1)*100
```