# Day of the month split on Python pandas dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following list of stocks:

[image]

For each one I would like to separate by day of month as this explanatory drawing:

[image]

With this separation I can perform the cumulative return for each day and separate by max and min cumulative returns for each stock symbol.

I am doing the following (example from another stock list) from SO:
[Call a report from a dictionary of dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63892673/call-a-report-from-a-dictionary-of-dataframes) :

```
data_dict = dict()  # create an empty dict here
for k, df in df_dict.items():
    df_dict[k]['Return %'] = df.iloc[:, 0].pct_change(-1)*100

    # aggregate the max and min of Return
    mm = df_dict[k]['Return %'].agg(['max', 'min'])  

    # add it to the dict, with ticker as the key
    data_dict[k] = {'max': mm.max(), 'min': mm.min()}  

# convert to a dataframe if you want
mm_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict, orient='index')

# display(mm_df)
          max      min
aapl  8.70284 -4.90070
msft  6.60377 -4.08443
```

This results in a linear analysis of the stocks in the list and do not separate by day as I wish to do as per drawing above..

Question:

- How can I insert a step to split by day of month and then perform the above code?

Comment: Someone can give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.groupby` and use `datetime.date()` as the grouping field. Then you can use `sum` operator on the group object to calculate daily return. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082784/pandas-dataframe-groupby-datetime-month/24083253) shows using `groupby` with datetime

Comment: I will check the post mentioned.