# How to export a dataframe to csv on local desktop

Tags: python, download

I have created a dataframe from an existing file.Now i am trying to download it onto my local desktop with the code as shown below-

data.to_csv(r'C:\Users\pmishr50\Desktop\Skills\python\new.csv')

The code doesnt show any error but i cnt find my file in the given path.
I have found results to download the data, also download the data to Google drive. But i wish to download the data to the path mentioned here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas to\_csv doesn't output the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54227746/pandas-to-csv-doesnt-output-the-file)

Comment: Can you read the file? If you run: `test=pandas.read_csv(r'C:\Users\pmishr50\Desktop\Skills\python\new.csv')` and `print(test)` does it print your dataframe?

Comment: do you run it on some server? what server? `to_csv()` expects that you run code on local desktop - and then it saves it on local desktop. When you run it on server, then it saves it on server becasue it treats server as its local computer. As I know it has no method to save it remotly from server to local desktop. But maybe server has other method to send it to your local desktop but it may depend what server you use and how it you use (ie. using JupyterLab)