# How to change jupyter notebooks working directory configuration

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Id like the working directory of all notebooks to be the location where I run the command from, not the location the notebook is at.

As an example:

```
root_folder/ 
    notebooks/
        subject_A/
            notebook.ipynb
    src/
        module.py

# notebook.ipynb

from src import module
```

I want to run `jupyter notebook` (or lab) from `root_folder` and import modules from the working directory. I dont consider [os.chdir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35665295/2926257) a good solution because moving the notebook to another folder will break the import. I'd also rather not add absolute paths inside the notebooks, this solution would not be exportable: my absolute path is not the same as yours.

I know I could add a `setup.py` to make `src` installable, but was looking for a more direct approach (I want to change the working directory, not install packages).

I also want an approach that is independent of the notebook location, it is the same regardless if it is at `notebooks/A` or in `notebook/A/B`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would try with `sys` and then import `module`. It does not change your cwd but you will be able to import your modules in `src`

```
import sys
sys.path.append("absolute/path/to/src")

from module import *
```

Answer (score 0):

Find `root_folder` like this:

```
import os 

# Get current working directory, in your case cwd is ../root_folder/notebooks/subject_A

cwd = os.getcwd()

root_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(cwd))
```

After finding `root_folder`:

```
path_to_src = os.path.join(root_folder, 'src')
```

And finally, append `path_to_src` to `sys.path` :

```
import sys
sys.path.append(path_to_src)
```

Now Python can import any modules from `src`. If the `root_folder` is moved to other system or directory the above-mentioned procedure will be able to import any modules from `src`.

Comment: Thanks for the help @pouya. This solution requires a different implementation if I move the notebook up or down a folder, does it not?

Comment: Your welcome. As you keep this filesystem for your project, the implementation needs no change.